# Show MsgBox only once

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script, that goes as follows:

1, it will run when particular sheet is selected

2, it will check if condition is True

3, if so, show MsgBox

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim current As Double
current = Round(((Range("AJ9").Value / Range("AG9").Value) * 100), 1)
If Range("AJ9").Value / Range("AG9").Value < 0.15 Then
    MsgBox "Here is some message and some value: " & current & "%."
End If
End Sub
```

I want to show this MsgBox only first time, when user come to the sheet. Now it pops up every time user get to the sheet. 
I have tried to use variable from different Sub, but it seems like it doesn't work.

```
Public read As Boolean
Sub readValue(Optional readArg As Boolean)
   MsgBox readArg 
   read = (readArg Or False)
End Sub
```

and then I modified first Sub like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim current As Double
current = Round(((Range("AJ9").Value / Range("AG9").Value) * 100), 1)
Call readValue
If read = False Then
    If Range("AJ9").Value / Range("AG9").Value < 0.15 Then
        MsgBox "Here is some message and some value: " & current & "%."
        readValue read = True
    End If
End If
```

But the `MsgBox readArg`  always says `False`. It's like it isn't sending value at all. Therefore MsgBox shows everytime user come to the sheet.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need a persistent variable to track whether or not the worksheet has been activated during this current user session or not.  This means you'll need to either use a Public variable, or store the variable in a worksheet cell, or perhaps in a hidden options worksheet.  You'd set that variable to False on workbook open, and then set it to True when the worksheet is activated.  That persistent variable is what should get referenced instead of creating a non-persistent additional Sub.  TLDR: What you did wrong was use a non-persistent Sub instead of a persistent variable.

Comment: FWIW the `Or False` part in `read = (readArg Or False)` is redundant/superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ByRef` assignment of an `Optional` parameter makes the mechanism rather flakey, and the flag shouldn't need to be `Public`.

Following execution, `read` is initialized with `False`, and then the `Activate` handler eventually runs; `readValue` doesn't specify a default for its optional parameter, so the first invocation (`Call readValue`, ...note that `Call` is redundant) pops a msgbox that says "False", and then `read = (readArg Or False)` evaluates to `False`... and there's the bug, because at this point you'd need the flag to be `True` - *unconditionally*.

You're on the right track, but it can be much simpler than that:

```
Option Explicit
Private alreadyPrompted As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    If alreadyPrompted Then Exit Sub

    If Range("AJ9").Value / Range("AG9").Value < 0.15 Then
        Dim current As Double
        current = Round(((Range("AJ9").Value / Range("AG9").Value) * 100), 1)

        MsgBox "Here is some message and some value: " & current & "%."
        alreadyPrompted = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Another way would be to make the flag a `Static` local; such declarations retain their value between procedure calls - be careful not to abuse it though, because this can easily become confusing:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Static alreadyPrompted As Boolean
    If alreadyPrompted Then Exit Sub

    If Range("AJ9").Value / Range("AG9").Value < 0.15 Then
        Dim current As Double
        current = Round(((Range("AJ9").Value / Range("AG9").Value) * 100), 1)

        MsgBox "Here is some message and some value: " & current & "%."
        alreadyPrompted = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Note that I've made the calculation of `current` conditional in both snippets, because the variable doesn't need to be computed if the condition isn't true in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, sir, worked like a charm and perfectly explained.(I might say, I check your profile and I'm seriously impressed by your skills)